# How to compute the maximum between an array and a number element by element?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array and I would like to have the maximum between each value and 0.

```
array([  7.1788812 ,   7.16842748,   7.1601692 ,   7.16941517,
   -30.89416777, -30.89403639, -30.89971925, -30.89529326,
   -31.59193447, -31.59202963])
```

Wanted result:

```
array([ 7.1788812 ,   7.16842748,   7.1601692 ,   7.16941517,0,0,0,0,0,0])
```

There are different ways to obtain the result but I would like something of short and very pythonic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`np.maximum` computes the element-wise maximum of array elements, and numpy has some broadcasting rules ( see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) ); so you can try this:

```
np.maximum(x, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `numpy.clip`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([  7.1788812 ,   7.16842748,   7.1601692 ,   7.16941517,
   -30.89416777, -30.89403639, -30.89971925, -30.89529326,
   -31.59193447, -31.59202963])
np.clip(a, 0, np.inf)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
np.where(a>= 0, a, 0)
```

`numpy.where` seems like what you're looking for. Gives 0 if the conditional is false.

Answer (score 1):

```
newArray = array([max(x,0) for x in OriginalArray])
```